# Params for namespaced resources (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, namespaces, parameters

Can anyone point me to info on how the name of the params object is generated?

I just spent far too long trying to access params[:venue_search] following a form submission, only to find I needed to be referring instead to params[:searches_venue_search] presumably because I've organised the venue_search resource into a "search" folder and/or because of the preceding "search" directory in the URL that I've specified in the routes.

What's the logic behind this, anyone?

The routes:

```
  resources :venue_searches, controller: 'searches/venue_searches', model: 'searches/venue_search', only: [:create, :new], path: "/search/venues"
  match "search/venues/show", to: "searches/venue_searches#show", as: :venue_search
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
get "search/venues/show", to: "search/venue_searches#show", as: :venue_search
```

This will generate following route

```
venue_search GET    /search/venues/show(.:format)                 search/venue_searches#show
```

Comment: So the name of the route is the same name I use when I want to access the params? Why is that? 

FYI I don't have an :id in these routes as I'm not saving the object in the database, just sending the params through to the show page where the search results will be displayed.

Comment: Yes I realise the route that will be created. I'm already posting to that route. My question is about the params.

Comment: btw your route is wrong. and giving error. check by running command `rake routes`

Comment: venue_searches POST   /search/venues(.:format)                               searches/venue_searches#create {:model=>"searches/venue_search"}

Comment: new_venue_search GET    /search/venues/new(.:format)                           searches/venue_searches#new {:model=>"searches/venue_search"}

Comment: venue_search        /search/venues/show(.:format)                          searches/venue_searches#show

Comment: Comments are not a good format for posting routes therefore I've posted the relevant routes one at a time for clarity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79409/discussion-between-user123-and-reb).